# MYSQL fetch_assoc() not behaving as expected with LEFT JOIN

Tags: php, mysql

I have a relatively simple SELECT query that is returning exactly the result I am looking for when I view the result from MySQL Workbench or phpMyAdmin. However, when displaying the results on a PHP webpage using `$query->fetch_assoc()` the joined column is returning blank for any result not present in the right-side table.

```
SELECT * 
FROM `users` u 
LEFT JOIN `grades` g ON u.`VID` = g.`VID` 
ORDER BY u.`VID` ASC
```

Since VID is the primary key on `users`, all rows have a value there. And, when run in MySQL Workbench or using phpMyAdmin, all rows display the correct value for VID as well. However, when using fetch_assoc(), the users who do not have an associated row in the `grades` table have the VID column blank in the returned result, despite having a VID value in the left table (`users`).

The only hacky way I've found to circumvent this is to specifically include the left-side VID value as a separate entity:

```
SELECT u.`VID` as theVID, u.*, g.* 
FROM `users` u 
LEFT JOIN `grades` g ON u.`VID` = g.`VID` 
ORDER BY u.`VID` ASC
```

But this feels hacky and inefficient and shouldn't be necessary. Why is fetch_assoc() returning a different result than the standard MySQL result?

Comment: You have `*` in the query. Are all the column names involved unique?

Comment: An index can only exist once in an array in PHP. `VID` is coming from the NULL table, not the one you want. Alias the column you want and it will be retrievable. See https://3v4l.org/Or3qu

Comment: just reference the columns you need to select with the table alias, e,g,. select u.VID, u.col1, u.col2, g.colx, g.coly from..

Comment: @Jayvee  Isn't that precisely what I have done in the second example I provided?  That is what I am currently using, I just thought I wouldn't have to do that using JOIN since the right side table values would only be used if the row exists. I guess I'm not doing anything wrong then.

Comment: @HenryFloyd , yes, I think it's good enough the only thing you can improve is that instead of using U.Vid, u.* ,g.*  you can just enumerate each column with the table reference so not to duplicate the common ones

Comment: @Jayvee There are no duplicate columns except VID.  I try to maintain first normal form and don't duplicate data across tables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the only common column name is the join attribute, you can use the USING clause:

```
SELECT *
FROM `users` 
LEFT JOIN `grades` USING(`VID`)
ORDER BY `VID` ASC
```

or NATURAL LEFT JOIN:

```
SELECT *
FROM `users` 
NATURAL LEFT JOIN `grades` 
ORDER BY `VID` ASC
```

https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/p2J1HMkxp2B5gZLii4zceM/0

Comment: This is precisely the behavior I was looking for.  I didn't realize `ON column = column` treated the common column differently. Thank you!